# How does C# (or any other language) read the code? I'm a very newie

Tags: c#, performance, loops, methods, logic

It does seems like I still don't get how programming works (maybe 'cause I've been learning C# for about 7 days or so) and I still don't know how it reads your code.

Look, I had to create the tic tac toe game using c# and the console. When I finally accomplished the task, I took a look at the correct way to do it and I used 500 lines when they used 200.

The point is they make a "Do While" loop and, inside of it, they use an "if" calling a method which use as parameters the number of the player and the input. Right when the "if" closes, they put the "Console.WriteLine" asking for the input THEY NEEDED TO USE RIGHT BEFORE. And when you run it, they ask you for it BEFORE doing anything. WHY IS THIS?

I can't figure out myself why it works like that. How can it even be possible for that "if" to work when they ask for your input right when it closes. This is the part of his code I mean:

```
 int player = 2;
 int input = 0;
 bool correctInput = true;

CreateBoard();

do
{
    if(player == 2)
    {
        player = 1;
        PutXorO(player, input);
    }else if(player == 1)
    {
        player = 2;
        PutXorO(player, input);
    }

    do
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\nPlayer{0}, please, select a number...", player);
        input = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    } while (!correctInput);

} while (true);
```

Edit: While writting this I think it's not that hard as I thought, but would love some help. Thx so much!

What I did before looking at the answer was putting all this kinda stuff where you ask in the first lines of my code, that's how my mind undertand this logic, but I need to change that so I can start thinking as a good programmer.

I truly want to improve, believe me. I'm upset with myself for this.

Comment: Stuff flows from top to bottom.  In this case, they initialized the `input` value to 0 and `player` to 2.  The first time through this loop, player 1 will choose value 0, because those variables already have values.  Only then do they ask for the player to make a move.  This is not a particularly good way to write this.

Comment: agreeing on the last sentence. good programming is not about writing short cryptic lines (there are exceptions in lowlevel or high performance programming). its about writing maintainable readable code in 90% of the time. so that is what you should learn. i can only repeat : this is not a particularly good way to write this

Comment: Do not use this as a _good_ learning example. It's not. Not only is the control flow... let's say surprising. It also heavily depends on methods' side-effects. It would definitely not pass a PR review by me.

Comment: To echo the comments of others - in programming there is rarely one "correct" way to solve a problem.  There are many ways to solve a problem, with some of them being gauged as more "correct" according to highly subjective criteria.  IMO, the code in the post is absolutely not a good way to write this code.  I would be confused for all the same reasons you are.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, it is not possible to say anything more without seeing the rest of the code but I'll try to explain the code as much as I can by also giving several insights.

As a general rule of thumb, code is read from top to bottom and left to right, with outer structures being read before their nested or inner components.

## The Code

As I've said before, I don't know the rest of the code. Therefore, I will make some assumptions.

The `do-while` loop serves a particular purpose. It is most commonly used when you have a situation as follows:

For simplicity's sake, imagine a program that continuously prompts the user to enter a number until the number is a "valid" number, i.e. the number is between 1 and 10.

With a normal `while` loop this would be done as such:

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter a number between 1 and 10: ");
int number = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

while (number < 1 || number > 10)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Invalid number. Enter a number between 1 and 10: ");
    number = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
}

Console.WriteLine("You entered a valid number: " + number);
```

In this example, we need to ask the number to the user before entering the loop. Alternatively, this could be achieved using a `do-while` loop.

```
int number;
        
do
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter a number between 1 and 10:");
    number = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
} 
while (number < 1 || number > 10);

Console.WriteLine("You entered a valid number: " + number);
```

In this case, the loop is initialized once, using a single  `Console.ReadLine()`.

In your code, this part of the program

```
do
{
    if(player == 2)
    {
        player = 1;
        PutXorO(player, input);
    }else if(player == 1)
    {
        player = 2;
        PutXorO(player, input);
    }

    do
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\nPlayer{0}, please, select a number...", player);
        input = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    } while (!correctInput);

} while (true);
```

is run on a `do-while` loop that is useless, it is no different from a `while(true)` loop. Hence it could be written as:

```
while (true)
{
    if(player == 2)
    {
        player = 1;
        PutXorO(player, input);
    }else if(player == 1)
    {
        player = 2;
        PutXorO(player, input);
    }

    do
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\nPlayer{0}, please, select a number...", player);
        input = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    } while (!correctInput);
}
```

When the program starts, `input` is initialized to be `0`. For this reason, the `PutXorO(player, input)` is working properly. But considering that neither of the players has yet made a move, the `PutXorO()` method can be assumed to be something like this:

```
public void PutXorO(int player, int input)
{
    if(input == 0)
    {
        return;
    }

    // The rest of the code
}
```

Next, the part where the second `do-while` loop comes into play. Now, this part is not very clear to me, simply due to this line:

```
while (!correctInput);
```

At the start of the code, `correctInput` is set to be `true`. Therefore, this while loop will never work as the variable `correctInput` is never changed in the loops themselves which means that the loop condition always resolves to `false`. I believe `correctInput` is changed in the method `PutXorO()` which is not only confusing but also useless.

## How Could It Be Done Alternatively?

In this part, I will try to write a tic tac toe game from scratch. Note that there may be several mistakes. I am sure people in the comments will fix those mistakes.

First, I will construct a simple board which will be a one dimensional string array. In the form:

```
/* The tic tac toe board looks like this, with locations from 1 to 9:
* -------------------------
* |      |       |        |
* |  1   |   2   |   3    |
* |      |       |        |
* -------------------------
* |      |       |        |
* |  4   |   5   |   6    |
* |      |       |        |
* -------------------------
* |      |       |        |
* |  7   |   8   |   9    |
* |      |       |        |
* -------------------------
*/

string[] TicTacToeBoard = new string[9];

// Initialize board
for (int i = 0; i < TicTacToeBoard.Length; i++)
{
    TicTacToeBoard[i] = string.Empty; 
}
```

Now I want to initialize several variables that I will use in my control flow:

```
int currentPlayer = 1; // The current player
bool gameOver = false; // Whether or not the game is going on
int moves = 0; // Keeping track of the moves to see if the board is filled
```

We need a simple loop that keeps track of the `gameOver` variable:

```
while (!gameOver)
{
    
}
```

We will ask for input for the location from the current player

```
while (!gameOver)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Player {currentPlayer}, it's your turn. Enter a location (1-9):"); 
    int input = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
}
```

At this point, we will have a method that will put the X or the O into the board and return true if the input is valid or false if it is not. I came up with this:

```
// Returns false if the location is invalid or already taken
static bool PutXorO(string[] board, int player, int location)
{
    if (location < 1 || location > 9)
    {
        return false;
    }

    if (player == 1 && board[location - 1] == string.Empty)
    {
        board[location - 1] = "X";
    }
    else if (player == 2 && board[location - 1] == string.Empty)
    {
        board[location - 1] = "O";
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Therefore, we can now put the input into the board or repeat the move if the input is invalid

```
while (!gameOver)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Player {currentPlayer}, it's your turn. Enter a location (1-9):"); 
    int input = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    if(PutXorO(TicTacToeBoard, currentPlayer, input))
    {
        // Valid Input, proceed with the code
    }
    // Invalid Input, loop back and ask the same player for an input
}
```

Now, if the input is invalid, the code will loop back and ask the same player for a new input. You could potentially add an error message but I chose not to. On the other hand, if the input is valid, we need to increase the move count,  check for wins or ties, and swap the current player.

```
while (!gameOver)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Player {currentPlayer}, it's your turn. Enter a location (1-9):"); 
    int input = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    if(PutXorO(TicTacToeBoard, currentPlayer, input))
    {
        moves++;

        // TODO: Check for wins
        ...
        //

        if(moves == 9)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("It's a tie!");
            gameOver = true;
        }

        currentPlayer = currentPlayer == 1 ? 2 : 1;
    }
}
```

In this case, if the move count is 9 and no player has won, it is a tie. Finally, all we have to do is a way to check all win conditions. For this I wrote the following method:

```
static bool CheckPlayerWin(string[] board, int player)
{
    string playerToken = player == 1 ? "X" : "O";

    int[][] winCombos = new int[][]
    {
        new int[] { 0, 1, 2 },
        new int[] { 3, 4, 5 },
        new int[] { 6, 7, 8 },
        new int[] { 0, 3, 6 },
        new int[] { 1, 4, 7 },
        new int[] { 2, 5, 8 },
        new int[] { 0, 4, 8 },
        new int[] { 2, 4, 6 }
    };

    foreach (var combo in winCombos)
    {
        if (board[combo[0]] == playerToken && board[combo[1]] == playerToken && board[combo[2]] == playerToken)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

This method checks the board for all win combinations. This method could be further wrapped in a `CheckWin()` method that will return the player that has one if there is any or `0` otherwise.

```
static int CheckWin(string[] board)
{
    if (CheckPlayerWin(board, 1)) return 1;
    if (CheckPlayerWin(board, 2)) return 2;
    return 0;
}
```

In the end the main loop could be completed as:

```
while (!gameOver)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Player {currentPlayer}, it's your turn. Enter a location (1-9):"); 
    int input = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    if(PutXorO(TicTacToeBoard, currentPlayer, input))
    {
        moves++;

        int playerWon = CheckWin(TicTacToeBoard);

        if(playerWon != 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Player {playerWon} has won the game!");
            gameOver = true;
        }
        else if(moves == 9)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("It's a tie!");
            gameOver = true;
        }

        currentPlayer = currentPlayer == 1 ? 2 : 1;
    }
}
```

Note that this code checks for a tie only if there is no winner in the ninth move.

The entire code becomes:

```
internal class Program
{
    /* The tic tac toe board looks like this, with locations from 1 to 9:
     * -------------------------
     * |      |       |        |
     * |  1   |   2   |   3    |
     * |      |       |        |
     * -------------------------
     * |      |       |        |
     * |  4   |   5   |   6    |
     * |      |       |        |
     * -------------------------
     * |      |       |        |
     * |  7   |   8   |   9    |
     * |      |       |        |
     * -------------------------
     */


    // Returns false if the location is invalid or already taken
    static bool PutXorO(string[] board, int player, int location)
    {
        if (location < 1 || location > 9)
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (player == 1 && board[location - 1] == string.Empty)
        {
            board[location - 1] = "X";
        }
        else if (player == 2 && board[location - 1] == string.Empty)
        {
            board[location - 1] = "O";
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    static bool CheckPlayerWin(string[] board, int player)
    {
        string playerToken = player == 1 ? "X" : "O";

        int[][] winCombos = new int[][]
        {
            new int[] { 0, 1, 2 },
            new int[] { 3, 4, 5 },
            new int[] { 6, 7, 8 },
            new int[] { 0, 3, 6 },
            new int[] { 1, 4, 7 },
            new int[] { 2, 5, 8 },
            new int[] { 0, 4, 8 },
            new int[] { 2, 4, 6 }
        };

        foreach (var combo in winCombos)
        {
            if (board[combo[0]] == playerToken && board[combo[1]] == playerToken && board[combo[2]] == playerToken)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    static int CheckWin(string[] board)
    {
        if (CheckPlayerWin(board, 1)) return 1;
        if (CheckPlayerWin(board, 2)) return 2;
        return 0;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] TicTacToeBoard = new string[9];

        // Initialize board
        for (int i = 0; i < TicTacToeBoard.Length; i++)
        {
            TicTacToeBoard[i] = string.Empty; 
        }

        int currentPlayer = 1;
        bool gameOver = false;
        int moves = 0;

        while (!gameOver)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Player {currentPlayer}, it's your turn. Enter a location (1-9):"); 
            int input = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            if(PutXorO(TicTacToeBoard, currentPlayer, input))
            {
                moves++;

                int playerWon = CheckWin(TicTacToeBoard);

                if(playerWon != 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Player {playerWon} has won the game!");
                    gameOver = true;
                }
                else if(moves == 9)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("It's a tie!");
                    gameOver = true;
                }

                currentPlayer = currentPlayer == 1 ? 2 : 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My initial tests show that this program kinda works. There may be several updates that could improve this program. For example, you could add a way to display the board with each move etc.

Don't hesitate to ask any question or point out any mistake I made.